# Dimension of an affine space

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry, integer-lattices

Let $v=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\Lambda\subset \mathbb R^n$ ($\Lambda$ is a discrete set) with $v\in\Lambda$. Consider the subset of $\mathbb R^n$ given by the set of those $x\in \mathbb R^n$ for which $\sum v_ix_i=|v|^2/2$; and for all $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in \Lambda$, we have $\sum a_ix_i\le |a|^2/2$. Can we get a necessary and sufficient condition on $v$ for which this will be an affine subspace of dimension $n-1$?

For reasons outlined in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5154.pdf) paper I believe that the condition must be $v^Ta<a^Ta$ for all $a\in\Lambda-\{0,v\}$. But there seems to be some easy reason apparently for this which I am unable to identify.

Comment: What makes you believe it will be an affine subspace?

Comment: Sorry. See the updated question.

Comment: Here's a counterexample for the condition you proposed: $v = 0$. Then $v^T a < a^T a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the subset under consideration is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$